# Not able to use wp_ajax_action hook for running a custom function in the settings page of a custom plugin on click of submit_button()

Tags: wordpress

I am working on creating a custom plugin in WordPress. I have created a settings page for the plugin by using add_menu_page() function and settings Api functions like add_settings_section, add_settings_field,register_settings.
I want to use ajax on the submit_button() in the settings page, so that I can match the settings being saved by some specific value before saving.
I am using wp_ajax action hook for this.
All the code I have checked from WordPress codex and is fine.
The wp_ajax_action hook is not working but, the function is not being called or hooked.
I have tried by placing the action for wp_ajax_action  on the construct fxn of plugin's file but its not working.
Please tell me how to do this.

Comment: Impossible to help without seeing your code

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Yes I am posting my code please check it below.

Answer (score 0):

Please visit below link
https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins
Wordpress provide many example for how to use its hooks
I hope this will helpful for You.

Comment: Thanks Madhavi. I have refered to this document already. And have coded everything according to this, but still it not working.

Answer (score 0):

Can you attached file here in txt mode so I can check .
and check this another example 
https://benmarshall.me/wordpress-ajax-frontend-backend/

Answer (score 0):

as my understanding you miss a action, try this function to  add.

```
{//already added}  add_action('wp_ajax_activation_match', 'activation_match'); 
{// new action }add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_activation_match','activation_match' ); //Use both action.
```

and make sure your script file included {// as example }

```
function my_admin_scripts() { wp_enqueue_script(....);}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_scripts' );
```